# Copy or Write file to remote machine using wmi c#

Tags: c#, wmi

I have to file copy/write to my remote machine(client) which is connected through my domain(server).

I had been work out with wmi [copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389332%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.but it helps only to copy the file from remote machine to local machine.

but I want write my files into remote machine windows directory.Please provide the way i can achieve my requirement using wmi c#.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the required privileges to do so through WMI, you can simply use the administrative shares and do it the normal way.

For example, copying a file to the computer *server1* into the *D:* partition into the folder named *Folder1*, you would do

```
copy yourfile.dat \\server1\d$\folder1\yourfile.dat
```

or use any other way to create a file there. The path name is valid for any method to create files.

Comment: need to run the query in cmd window?

Comment: The example, yes. You can use any other way of file handling, too. The path is not cmd specific.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply,I got it your point.Is it possible for remote domain machines with applying credentials ?.

Comment: If the user of your program does not have the privileges, but another user does, you may want to [impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/w070t6ka(v=vs.110).aspx) this user. If you use cmd, you can just select "Run as other user" from the context menu (press left-ctrl and shift when you right click the cmd icon to see this conext menu entry).